# Submitting a mailto string to Mailto doesn't often work

Tags: c#, mailto

I'm writing an app (in C#). Among other things the app lets users send emails. The app creates a mailto string and then invokes ProcessStart(mailto);

So my code gets to the mail sending part, where it sends an email via mailto. I'm on the same machine where I get my gmail. When it invokes ProcessStart(mailto) I see the Microsoft Mail program operate. This is good in that I don't want the app to send email without the user's interaction.

I click send in the Mail program and...nothing happens. Mail seems to have sent the email but my gmail (in Chrome, on the same machine) doesn't get it. It's not in spam or trash, or even in the sent folder, either in Gmail or in the Mail program. Am I doing something wrong? The Outbox (in the Microsoft Mail program) is empty.

The mailto string looks like this:

```
"mailto:billy10101010@gmail.com,  sally1010101010@gmail.com?subject=Test Mail&body=test"
```

And sometimes, the mail is sent via the Mail program and received.

I sent emails to other people (not on my own computer). One got it, another did not.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a C# problem at all

Comment: Let's be fair, it doesn't let people send email, it just creates a hyperlink with a mailto format. I am not to familiar with the multiple recipients list, but couldn't you send it to billy and put sally in cc field, does it still give a similar problem?

Comment: For email to work you need to set up account information in the user mail in teh control panel.  The default application is Outlook and you may run into issues having both outlook and gmail for same user.  Then gmail you have to use secure email and you need to check the gmail webpage if you are going to use snmtp.

Comment: What I want to do is allow the user to send emails from the app. But ProcessStart invokes Windows 10 Mail. And now the user, who may have never used this app, will have to set up an email account with this app with Outlook?

Comment: The issue is that my app will be unaware of the user's default email app. Is there a way to use Process.Start(mailto) without the app "knowing" what the setup is for the user or requiring the user to do anything but click send or delete? The Microsoft Mail app is very opaque. I can click "send" but nothing happens except the message disappears (most of the time).